# Flash Builder "Unable to Connect" error

Tags: flash, debugging, flashbuilder4

I am trying to debug a Flash Web Application using Flash Builder 4.  However, I keep getting this error:

> Unable to Connect
>
> Unable to connect to
> the application to fetch profile data.
> Please try profiling the application
> again.

I am using Internet Explorer 8 (the same problem also occurs with Internet Explorer 7) with Adobe Flash Player 10.1.102.64 (the Debug Player).  In other words, I installed the latest of everything.

For my launch configuration, I have used the path to an HTML file.  This works fine for debugging but does not seem to work for profiling.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Version 10.0 of the Flash player (the debug version).  [Version 10.1 does not work with the profiler.](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2943410?tstart=0)

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed the debug version of Flash Player?

Please check [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Debug Player.  I checked this on the page you gave.

Comment: Have you tried changing the port to connect to the profiler? It might be blocked by your firewall. You can change it in Window->Preferences->Flex->Profiler

Answer (score 0):

try checking your output folder for the build is pointing to where you expect (and thus can see its dependencies)