# Flex Builder - Profiler - Can't run profiler "unable to connect to the application to fetch profile data please try profiling the application again"

Tags: actionscript, flex4, flexbuilder, profiler

I use Flex Builder 4 Plugin on Eclipse 3.6.2 on Windows 7 64 bits. Of course, I use Eclipse 32 bits with Java 32 bits.
When I run AIR application in Profiler mode, it gave me the classic error:
"unable to connect to the application to fetch profile data please try profiling the application again"

1) I already try putting mm.cfg in my c:\users\username\ , and my Eclipse Project folder and it still didn't work. Here's what written in mm.cfg



    `PreloadSwf=file:///D:/project/.metadata/.plugins/com.adobe.flash.profiler/ProfilerAgent.swf?host=localhost&port=8888`



`AS3Sampling=1

AS3AutoStartSampling=1

ErrorReportingEnable=1

TraceOutputFileEnable=1

MaxWarnings=100`


2) I already disable Firewall and Antivirus, port 8888 has been open for TCP connection for both incoming and outgoing.

3) I try with both Flex SDK 4.0 and 4.1

4) I update my flash player debug version to 10.2 because I search somewhere that 10.1 doesn't support Profiler, still didn't work, even though my project is AIR. (By the way, I have try with Flash Project and it still not work)

5) I have also try remove the first line, the one that indicates PreloadSwf, and it still doesn't work

I also install this similar setting on fresh machine, using Windows 7 32 bits, and it give the same error.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas :

1. Change the port to be 9999
2. Are you getting any errors in out Output? (PreloadSwf paths must be local trusted: )
3. Change your browser! (Preferences/General/Web Browser) Maybe Firefox is acting scummy
4. Are you running flash debugger in that specific browser?
5. Possibly editing your mm.cfg file (i.e. check out here : http://jpauclair.net/2010/02/10/mmcfg-treasure/)

Comment: 1)
2) How to make PreloadSwf local trusted?
3) I already try creating dummy Flash project and test with IE and Firefox, and as stated above, my project is AIR. 
4) Of course, I ran 10.2 debugger as state above

Answer (score 1):

I just found that on Windows 7, if you start your Flash Builder or Eclipse with administration privileges, the profiler will not connect. Be sure to start your Flash Builder or Eclipse without “Start as Administrator” (I had foolishly created an Icon to start Eclipse which include this option on)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't try your answer anymore because I switch to Mac!

Comment: I also made the shortcut for FB to start with Admin privileges, but after running it without privileges, the profiler still won't connect.

Answer (score 0):

it appears as if this question was already answered over here

[Flash Builder "Unable to Connect" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854098/flash-builder-unable-to-connect-error)

Answer (score 0):

I have found an inconvenient solution. By creating another user in Windows, and give it administrator privilege. I can add that very same project and Profiler work just fine. Might be there is some problem in my way of creating user. (This is quite a mystery, because I have 2 PCs with different spec, running almost the same application, and receive this same problem on my user account. I still have no idea why another user name give different result, but different PC won't.)