# Does Flash Builder 4 Profiler work with a Flex 4.5 project?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, profiler

I'm trying to use the Profiler for the first time so I don't know much about it. But it doesn't seem to work.

I run my project under profiler, it says it is running, but no window shows up. Nothing. I can see the project's icon down there but I see no window at all.

Can this be cause by the fact that I'm using Flex 4.5? Or am I missing something?

Updated: Here's a screenshot of the Profiler running the an app. You can the app in the dock and it shows its live objects, but I don't see the apps' window and cannot interact with it. The app is just a simple 400x400 window with some black shapes in it.

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance,
Nuno

Comment: Quantify"not work".  I would expect the profiler to work fine if you have Flex 4.5 set up using the multiple SDK feature.

Comment: Sorry :) "not work" means the Profiler appears to be working but I cannot see the app's window. Please check the screenshot above.

Comment: I don't use the profiler all that much; but will breakpoints fire?  If so, is it possible the app is "hung" waiting for the debugger to stop.  I'm just guessing though, it looks like there are some more details in actual answers.

Comment: hi, for a moment I had hope. but after deleting all breakpoints I still get the same behavior :(

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you may not be running it in a debug player.  [Check to make sure](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html).

Comment: I see. I didn't know this. But anyway it's an AIR application. So I thought it wouldn't need the flash player anyway. Besides, I do debug all the time, just by pressing the button right next to the one I used to start the Profiler. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, what does it do?  Are you sure you're pressing the right on?  Can you show screenshots of everything?

Comment: I just uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: Okay, so your profiler is working, but your app isn't starting up properly.  Try using a blank Air project with just a button in it and try again.

Comment: I just created a Blank AIR project with just one button. Exactly the same happened. Just like the screenshot I posted :(

Comment: Either it's some configuration (I didn't change anything besides the obvious, as far as I remember) or some strange bug or the Profiler is incompatible with Flex 4.5...

Comment: Possible, though I'm not seeing the same issue.  Try different things to see if you can isolate the problem.  Could be an issue with Flash Builder which you can try reinstalling.  I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4854098/275643). It seems the profiler [doesn't work well with Flash Player 10.1](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2943410?tstart=0).

Comment: hum... I checked and my version is MAC 10,3,181,14. But I wonder if this is still valid while running an AIR application. Does AIR use my current flash player? Or does it have its own?

Comment: @nununo From http://www.uiresourcecenter.com/ui-technologies/adobe-air/faq.html?s=3_2_3#compare3 : It looks like AIR is one deployment method while Flash Player is another. Worth checking into whether the AIR runtime you have has the same issue as the Flash Player though.